# C# - Remove last character from string on keydown

Tags: c#

I'm using this at the moment to remove the last character of my string if the back key is pressed, however if I hold the key it isn't removing characters from the string, while the rest of the conditionals work fine adding characters to the string. I suppose that the Remove function don't work well on a kind of loop.

```
if (key == Keys.Back)
{
    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

**Update**: I thought that it was removing characters on key press, but **it didn't.** Thanks for the answers of this stupid error.

Comment: Please define "isn't working"

Comment: @Sayse It's not removing characters from the string. Already solved.

Comment: Yes, but in future, remember that "not working" is extremely unhelpful when trying to solve a problem.

Comment: I see, sorry! Question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Remove` method doesn't modify the `text`. It returns a new string, you need to assign it back to your `textBox` (or the `text`, if you want to manipulate `text` variable):

```
textBox1.Text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Damn! I thought that it worked on the key press. Thanks! I will mark this answer as the correct one as you was the first, sorry about this stupid error.

Answer (score 2):

**[strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)**, so the method `Remove` would return a new string. It will not modify the existing string. To see the change assign the result back to your `text` variable.

```
text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working, replace with:

```
text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i get also an upvote for posting the same answer like everybody else -.-

```
text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Everybody gets the upvote! Just kidding, I only upvoted the answers that happened at the same time.